# Get rid of file icon shadow when file is not saved in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, icons

When a file was just edited and not saved in the Xcode editor the icon of the file in the right pane is darkened a little, and because I have OCD this drives me absolutely crazy and I end up having to click Ctrl+S every time I do anything as simple as commenting a line of code or moving a button 1 pixel in storyboard.

I am using `Xcode 10.1 Beta 2`, but this happens in all versions of Xcode.

How do you make it so the file is never darkened?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in Xcode and I always command s everything as well. I have looked for a way to disable this, but for now I don’t think there is a way... Maybe they’ll add a way to turn this off in another update soon :)